# Parallel translation on surfaces

Tags: riemannian-geometry, surfaces

Parallel translation of a vector along a geodesic in a surface is characterized by the following three properties:

1. The vector being transported moves continuously.
2. It has constant norm.
3. It maintains a constant angle with the geodesic.

In [V.I. Arnold's book on mechanics](http://books.google.com.uy/books?id=Pd8-s6rOt_cC&lpg=PP1&ots=uKnfvGEGPw&dq=V.I.%2520arnold&pg=PA301#v=onepage&q=V.I.%2520arnold&f=false) he uses this starting point to define parallel translation along other curves.  He does this by approximating a general curve by a concatenation of small geodesic segments.

Another way of formalizing Arnold's idea is to calculate for each tangent vector $(p,\dot{p}) \in TS$ ($S$ a Riemannian surface) and each vector $v \in T_pS$ the derivative $H(p,\dot{p})(v)$ of the parallel transport of $v$ along the geodesic with initial condition $(p,\dot{p})$.  Then we say a curve $t \mapsto (p(t),v(t))$ is parallel if:
$v'(t) = H(p(t),p'(t))(v(t))$ for all $t$.

My question is the following:  Is there a conceptual proof that $H(p,\dot{p})(v)$ depends linearly on $\dot{p}$?

In other words:  Why does parallel transport define a Horizontal **linear** subspace in $T_{(p,v)}TS$?

Of course one can verify this by calculating $H$ explicitly, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I see is to define parallel translation the usual way.
(This angle property as well as linearity is evident.)
Then show that angle property alone plus approximation give the same translation.